# css rule to apply if only one element sits next to other element

Tags: html, css

I'd like to ask a question to see IF this is possible in CSS. It may not be: I'm prepared to make some styling concessions.

The context: I'm working on re-styling and redesigning an existing blog. This has over 80 posts that (for the most part) use the same markup. So what I'm trying to do is apply styling that works with the existing html - adding classes and changing orders means going through all posts and will take hours.

Markup example of one post:

```
<p>Block of text </p> 

<img src="example">

<p>Block of text </p> 
<img src="example">
<img src="example">

<p>Block of text </p> 
<img src="example">
```

This is an example: the order of the images and paragraphs will vary from post to post so this will be completely randomised.

What I'm trying to do is apply a 50% width styling to images that follow each other up, so they sit next to each other.

Like this: □ □

I'd like to style images that sit on their own to be at fullwidth - 100%

Is there a way to achieve this using CSS?

CSS rules like nth-of-type(3) will not work - the order of the images and p tags is completely randomised, so where in one post the 3rd img tag will be placed on its own, in another this will have to sit next to another image.

A rule like img + img would work for the second image, but I would need the first image to also apply the same styling. A rule like p + img will also cause the single images to shrink.

Any suggestions? An answer of 'this cannot be done' is also fine as I'll know to stop trying.

Comment: I need to think about whether css can do this (my intuition says no). What about a javascript solution??

Answer (score 3):

Flexbox can do this. I applied flex to body but it should be the container in your code:

```css
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
p {
 width:100%;
}
img {
  width:50%;
  min-width:0;
  flex-grow:1; /* this will do the trick when the image is alone */
}
```

```html
<p>Block of text </p> 

<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/107/800/400.jpg">

<p>Block of text </p> 
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/106/800/400.jpg">
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/17/800/400.jpg">

<p>Block of text </p> 
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/108/800/400.jpg">

<p>Block of text </p> 
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/104/800/400.jpg">
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/108/800/400.jpg">
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/175/800/400.jpg">
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/125/800/400.jpg">
```

Or like below if you want to apply this to image when there is no image with it even if the number is odd.

```css
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
p {
 width:100%;
}
img {
  width:50%;
  min-width:0;
}
p + img {
  flex-grow:1; /* this will do the trick when the image is alone */
}
```

```html
<p>Block of text </p> 

<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/107/800/400.jpg">

<p>Block of text </p> 
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/106/800/400.jpg">
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/17/800/400.jpg">

<p>Block of text </p> 
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/108/800/400.jpg">

<p>Block of text </p> 
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/104/800/400.jpg">
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/108/800/400.jpg">
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/175/800/400.jpg">
```

Comment: The first one was perfect for me! I was already using flex (using bootstrap) but I'm fairly new to it so hadn't used flex-grow yet. Thank you very much!